# Low bandwidth electronic filter

Tags: electrical-engineering, rf-electronics

Is it possible, under current technology, to have an electronic filter in the microwave range (100 MHz to 300 GHz) with very low bandwidth , say 100 to 1000 Hz?

If yes,  then what is the basic technology behind it? Any example would be great. Smallest bandwidth filters I am aware is that of GSM mobiles at 200kHz.

Comment: Are you willing to design & fab your own?

Comment: A better match in electrical engineering...